# How can I write to console in MS Windows with yasm?

Tags: windows, console, yasm

I tried this code (using interruptions), but it is for DOS:

```
mov eax, 42 ; write 42 to console
mov ecx, 10 ; in decimal
out_int_loop:
    xor edx, edx
    div ecx
    push eax
        add dl, '0' ; one digit 
        mov ah, 2 ; 2 is code for writing character
        int 21h
    pop eax
    cmp eax, 0
    jnz out_int_loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [`WriteConsoleA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from winapi.

Also I used [`GetStdHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get `stdout`.

To import this functions you need these lines:

```
extern  __imp__GetStdHandle@4
extern  __imp__WriteConsoleA@20
```